# Resources - NotFoundException when accessing literals

Tags: android, android-resources

No one of the translated strings are working at this moment, so the app always take the main strings file key.

Debugging, if i try to see the id of a key it returns a value. For example `R.string.app_name` returns `1900088` but getString(R.string.app_name) returns `Method threw 'android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException' exception.` with cause `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1cfe38`.

The strings files have no errors. I really dont know how to proceed with this

EDIT:

using the same files in a new project worked perfectly

Comment: You've said that it's always using the strings from the main file but then you've said that getting the string throws an error? Which one is it?

Comment: @HenryTwist both. Where i have `getString(R.string.key)` i get the main file key. If i write that sentence on the debugger i get the exception. Thats why im confused. And i know the files are ok because if i switch them they work perfectly and the app is working. But it doesnt get translations

Comment: Ah I see, to be honest I've had issues with the debugger and resources not playing well together so that might be irrelevant. Very bizarre though, is your project open source?

Comment: @HenryTwist no, it isnt even mine, im making some fixes on it. I already tried deleting the build folders. Now im trying by re-adding the translations

Comment: @HenryTwist i found the issue and post an answer in case you are interested. It was a gradle config issue

Comment: Ah I see, glad you found the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was in the gradle for the app module. There was a `resConfig "zz"` than can lead to this. Removing this line avoids all translation problems